# ceneOs8:Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: linux, ping

> Windows hosts can connect to the Internet, Linux can connect to the
> Internet, but Linux can't ping the Internet, I'm using centOs8,Windows
> hosts can connect to the Internet, Linux can connect to the Internet,
> but Linux can't ping the Internet, I'm using centOs8,before I modified
> the file  etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo ,it still can get
> online,is this reason?

[linux can't ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auIll.png)
[windows can ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6HoB.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could ping a same IP address in two OS